# Navigation function not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

I have write a lwc component to navigate from sign in page. Navigation function is not working.

My code

```
import { LightningElement ,track} from 'lwc';
import doLogin from '@salesforce/apex/loginController.doLogin';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class FaClientInvite extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) 
{
@track password;
   @track email;
   @track welcomeMessage;
   // @track errorCheck;
   // @track errorMessage;
   connectedCallback(){
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0");
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
}
    handleEmailChange(event)
        {
        if(event.target.value){
            this.email = event.target.value;
            console.log('emailHandler',this.email);
        } else {
            this.email = event.target.value;
        }
    }
     handlePasswordChange(event)
     {  
        this.password = event.target.value;
    }
     handleLogin(event)
     { 
        console.log('handlLogin');
       if(this.email && this.password)
       {
       const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'SignIn Successful!',
            variant: 'success',
        }); 
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            console.log('email : ',this.email);
            event.preventDefault();
        doLogin({ email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .then((result)=> {
            this.isError = false;
            console.log('Result is: ', this.email)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;      
                this.errorCheck = true;
                this.errorMessage = error.body.message;
            }); 
            navigateToHome();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('elsePart');
        }
        //return this.userName;
    }
    navigateToHome()
    {
        console.log('navigation');
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__FaClientHome' 
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `this` before the method name from where you are calling.

```
handleLogin(event) { 
       console.log('handlLogin');
       if(this.email && this.password) {
        const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'SignIn Successful!',
            variant: 'success',
        }); 
        this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            console.log('email : ',this.email);
            event.preventDefault();
        doLogin({ email: this.email, password: this.password })
        .then((result)=> {
            this.isError = false;
            console.log('Result is: ', this.email)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;      
                this.errorCheck = true;
                this.errorMessage = error.body.message;
            }); 
            this.navigateToHome();//here added 'this'
        } else {
            console.log('elsePart');
        }
        //return this.userName;
}
navigateToHome() {
        console.log('navigation');
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__FaClientHome' 
            },
        });
}
```

The **“this**” [keyword](https://www.salesforceben.com/30-salesforce-lightning-developer-interview-questions-answers/#:%7E:text=7.,be%20from%20within%20the%20LWC.) can be found in both Aura and LWC, and their uses are quite similar.

Within LWC, the keyword can be used to access any component property or method.
since **“this”** points to the calling context of the current code.
which in most cases will be from within the LWC.